# JS OOP calling a method from the constructor

Tags: javascript, oop

How do I call a method from inside my class' constructor in JavaScript?

I have the following Class:

```
function Aclass(){
    this.classValues = this.classMethod.call();
}
Aclass.prototype.classMethod = function(){
    return 'Hello World';
}
```

I initialize the class:

```
var test = new Aclass();
```

I get the following error:

*Aclass.prototype.classMethod is undefined*

I'm a newbie with JS OOP and would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: For me too on Firefox 4.

Comment: Awkward... I guess it's something else on the page that's throwing my code off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you put the line

```
var test = new Aclass();
```

Before the rest of your code? That would result in the error you described.

Comment: That's it! That's what I did. Thanks!